# "Could you please to tell more.." vs "Could you please tell more"

Tags: infinitives

I can't find rule work this questions.

"Could you please **to** tell more about some details" or
"Could you please tell more about some details".

maybe, english has words with infinitive or without ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is very simple. After a [modal verb](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/modalintro.html) like "could" or "can" we always use a **bare infinitive**; that is, the infinitive form of the verb without "to".

> Could you please tell me more about some of these details?
>
> Would you mind telling me more about these details?

See the link above for more examples of modal verbs.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular context both examples are incorrectly constructed as the verb **tell** requires a direct object, a noun or a pronoun:

> Could you please tell **me/him her, etc.** or **John/Mary/Joe, etc.** more about some details?

As regards the use of **to**, it would be inappropriate, a verb construct when using an auxiliary requires the bare infinitive.